# How to clean oil from cooling system?

Tags: oil, citroen, coolant-reservoir, picasso

I'm trying to sell my Citroen Picasso 2.0 HDI and got scammed by buyers putting used oil into the header tank of the cooling system and telling me that the head gasket had blown.

Now I need to figure out how to clean up the mess they left. The engine has been run so oil may have been pumped throughout the cooling system.

Comment: Thought it worth trying to clean up your question, I had to guess a bit about what happened. If I blew it feel free to correct or to revert it.

Answer (score 2):

Start by getting as much of the oil as you can out of the header tank, then do a thorough flush of the cooling system. If you have a plastic overflow tank you may want to clean it with a bit of detergent if any of the oil got into it.

Comment: What ever is easily available and reasonably priced at your local parts store should be just fine. For your specific problem you could probably even use some household dish detergent. You just want to try to get as much of the oil out of the system as you can. Detergent will emulsify it and help to keep it in suspension so that it will come out when you flush out the cooling system.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry you ran into such unpleasant people.

Comment: We used automatic dishwasher detergent because it produces very little foam and therefore is less likely to trap gas pockets while running. Gas pockets can lead to overheating, both localized and system-wide.

Comment: thanks guys luckily the oil the that's put in was so think I just sat in top of header tank so was quick fix messy but done. thanks for your help